# PermissionEvaluator custom implementation autowiring in one service class but not in other

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have defined a custom PermissionEvaluator :-

```
public class AppPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {
    ...
}
```

In the config class I register this bean :-

```
/**
 * Registers custom Permission evaluator.
 */
@Bean
public PermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator() {
    return new AppPermissionEvaluator();
}
```

I have two `@service` classes where I'm trying to autowire this class.

```
@Autowired
private AppPermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator;
```

If I directly autowire the class, it works in one service class but in the other service class it throws an exception `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean ...`

Autowiring the interface works in both service class. I would really like to is it wrong to autowire the class directly and how is it working in one service class but not in other?

Comment: Are both service classes in the same module?

Comment: If you return a PermissionEvaluator  in the bean definition, I recommed that you autowire the same class in you services.

Comment: @AlanHay what do you mean by module? They are in the same package.